# I can't understand why posts are not loading in firebase

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase

firebase does not write, although it seems to be syntactically correct. The application compiles, but no writes take place.

The documentation also seems to be correct.

the logic is simple. The user uploads a file from the phone, the file is sent to the repository

```
    @IBAction func addButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        ProgressHUD.show("Waiting...", interaction: false)
        if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4){
            let photoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: https://example.com).child("posts").child(photoIdString)
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                let photoUrl = storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {url, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Failed to download url:", error!)
                        return
                    } else {
                        let url = url?.absoluteString
                        self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: url!)
                    }
                })
    })
        }
    }
                
    func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
        let newPostId = postsReference.childByAutoId().key
        let newPostReference = postsReference.child(newPostId!)
        newPostReference.setValue(["photoUrl": photoUrl], withCompletionBlock: {
            (Error, ref) in
            if Error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(Error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")
        })
    }
}
extension PerformViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
        print("Did finish picking media")
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage ] as? UIImage{
            selectedImage = image
            photo.image = image
        }
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Troubleshooting code before posting the question is often helpful... and you may even answer your own question! Add a breakpoint here `if let profileImg = ` and run. Then, step through the code line by line examining vars and code execution along the way. When you find something unexpected, voila! That's what to investigate further to determine the cause. I suspect that line `if let profileImg =` where you put the breakpoint because if either of those var are nil, the code will silently fail and you'll never know why.

Comment: Also, 'does not write' is quite vague; *what* doesn't write? ...and the title has nothing to do with the question; the title states *posts don't load* and the question itself is about *writing data*

Comment: @Jay oh sorry. I misspoke.  I mean that there are no records in the database. Specifically, the user's photos are not uploaded to the database. I hope you understand me; Thanks for your comment, I will go look for the error

Comment: @Jay  I found what the problem was, thanks for the help)